# App Pool connection to SQL Server using Azure AD auth

Tags: sql-server, iis, odbc, application-pool

I have two VMs built in Azure. Both Servers run Windows 2022 OS and one has SQL Server 2022 CU4. Both are added to Azure AD and SQL Server is setup to authenticate to Azure AD. They are both in the same network. I have been able to add an Azure AD authenticated account as a login to SQL and set the same account to run an App pool in IIS on the other server. I setup a SQL Alias on the Web server.

I can only get an ODBC connection to successfully connect when using a SQL auth account.... I need the app pool using the Azure account to talk to SQL Server and this is the only way I know how to test but it's failing. Please help.